# CoreGraphics (drawRect) for drawing label's and UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-graphics

I have a `UITableViewCell` in which inside it I have 5 `UILabel` a `UIButton` and a `UIImageView` that fills out the cell as background. The performance seems to be a bit slow, so I was thinking of using `CoreGraphics` to improve it. Is it true that using `CoreGraphics` instead of `UILabel` as `subViews` will make things much faster? If yes why?

I have the following code to draw shadow on the cells:

```
[self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.layer setShadowRadius:10.0];
[self.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
[self.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.frame] CGPath]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, (as Gavin indicated) I would say that you have to first confirm that the subviews are indeed causing a jitter in your scrolling.

When I'm testing UITableViewCell scrolling performance, I often use the Time Profiler in Instruments.  Switch to Objective-C Only in the left-hand panel, and look at what is taking the most time on your Main Thread.  If you see lots of time spent on rearranging (layout) or drawing of subviews, you may need to use CoreGraphics.  If the time instead is spent on allocation/deallocation, then you may want to examine how your subviews are reused if at all.  If they are not being reused, then of course this can cause performance problems.

Then of course, you should look at compositing.  If your subviews are not opaque (identify this through the CoreAnimation instrument), then the performance may be seriously impacted.

Also of note -- realize that shadows are expensive to draw, and depending on your implementation, they may be redrawing on every frame!  Your best option is to make sure that any CALayer shadows are fully rasterized, and have a path defined so live computations from the pixel mask don't have to be made.

If finally, you identify that the layout and redrawing of each subview individually is causing the slowdown, then I have a couple of points/explanations:

1. Your implementation of the drawing routine for your table view cell will probably be slower than the highly optimized drawing that Apple has written for its views.  So you won't win any battles re-implementing drawing of UIImageView itself.  Performance gains instead come from two places when drawing with CoreGraphics: a.) Pre-rendering of previously non-opaque views, and reduction of time spent in the layout phase of the view drawing cycle - this reduces the workload on the GPU/CPU when scrolling.  b.) Reduction in time switching CG contexts for individual view drawing.  Each element now draws into the same graphics context at the same time, reducing switching costs.
2. Drawing in drawRect using CoreGraphics on the main thread draws using the CPU, and depending on how complex your cells are, this may cause jitters of its own.  Instead, consider drawing in a background thread to a separate CGContext, then dispatching a worker to insert the contents of the drawing as a CGImageRef into a CALayer, or as a UIImage in a UIImageView.  There is a naive implementation on GitHub: https://github.com/mindsnacks/MSCachedAsyncViewDrawing
3. If you do decide to go with background CoreGraphics drawing, be warned that at present (December 2012), I believe there is a bug in the NSString drawing categories when drawing on background threads that results in a fallback to webkit which is absolutely not thread safe.  This will cause a crash, so for the present time, make sure that the asynchronous drawing is done in a serial GCD/NSOperation queue.

Comment: super awesome tips! exactly what I needed. Can you tell me on how to make CALayer shadwos fuly rasterized? I have added the shadow code on the original post for you to see

Comment: I strongly `UILabel` simply uses UIKit's `NSString`-drawing methods; Apple's code is rarely as "highly optimized" as they'd like you to believe. UIImageView is different; it overrides `-displayLayer:` and approximately does `self.layer.contents = self.image.CGImage;` which simply composites it on the GPU (though the image still has to be decompressed on the CPU).

Comment: @tc - I think you missed my point. I was trying to make it clear that the performance enhancements in this case would not come from the actual CG drawing code itself.  Which was the actual question: "Is it true that using CoreGraphics instead of UILabel as subviews will make things much faster? If yes why?"I would also like to say that Apple's implementation of UIImageView and UILabel may not be much (or any) faster than using the our own implementation of these methods... but I doubt they're much slower, and they're probably going to break less often.

Comment: @adit - tc gave the code for layer rasterization in his answer.

Comment: @OCRickard when I switch to Objective-C only in time profiler, it gives me an empty table

Comment: ...not sure what the problem was here, but maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818149/time-profiler-instruments-not-showing-objective-c-functions

Answer (score 2):

On the simulator, **Debug**→**Color Blended Layers**. Red is bad, green is good.

More accurately, red means that the GPU needed to do an alpha blend. The main cost is in the memory bandwidth required to draw the pixels twice and possibly re-fetch the extra texture. Completely transparent pixels are *really* bad.

Three fixes (all of which reduce the amount of red), which you should consider before diving into Core Graphics:

- Make views opaque when possible. Labels with the background set to `[UIColor clearColor]` can often be set to a flat colour instead.
- Make views with transparency as small as possible. For labels, this involves using `-sizeToFit/-sizeThatFits:` and adjusting layout appropriately.
- Remove the alpha channel from opaque images (e.g. if your cell background is an image) — some image editors don't do this, and it means the GPU needs to perform an alpha test and might need to render whatever's behind the image.

Additionally, turn on **and Color Offscreen-Rendered** (possibly after turning off Color Blended Layers so it's easier to see). Offscreen-rendered stuff appears in yellow, and usually means that you've applied a layer mask. These can be very bad for performance; I don't know if CoreAnimation caches the masked result.

Finally, you can make CoreAnimation rasterize the cell by setting `cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES` (you might also need `cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` on retina devices; I forget if this is done automatically). The main benefit is that it's easy, and it's also more efficient than rendering the image view yourself in Core Graphics. (The benefit for labels is reduced since the text needs to be rendered on the CPU.)

Also note that view animations will be affected. I forget what setting CALayer.shouldRasterize does (it might re-rasterize it every frame of the animation, which is a bit wasteful when it'll only be drawn to screen once), but using Core Graphics will (by default) stretch the rendered content during the animation. See CALayer.contentsGravity.

Comment: when you say make view opaque does that mean set opaque to YES?

Comment: also what if I can't make the labels to have a background color. i.e: opaque, it needs to be clear because I have a UIImageView behind it that needs to be displayed, so setting it to opaque would be weird @tc

Comment: For labels, setting the background colour to an opaque colour also sets opaque to YES.

Comment: If you cannot make the labels opaque, then an alpha blend will need to happen somewhere. My point is not that you should get rid of all alpha blending, but that you should remove it where it's easy to do before deciding to rasterize the whole cell or draw everything with Core Graphics. If you do rasterize the cell, remember to check rotation performance (unless you're sure that your app will never need to support rotations) and animations like switching into/out of edit mode.

Comment: How do I remove alpha blending on UILabels?

Comment: As I have stated, they are optimizations worth considering *where it's easy to do.* You can get rid of the alpha blend by rendering the background at an appropriate offset in the label, but that may be slower as it does more work on the CPU. OTOH, it is certainly worth running with "Color Blended Layers" and "Color Offscreen-Rendered" (separately) and fixing all the low-hanging fruit.

Answer (score 1):

What evidence do you have to suggest that what you have in the views is causing the performance issues? This is a deep black hole that can suck you in, so be sure you know the problem is where you think it is.

Are you preloading all your data? Have you pre-downloaded the images? What you're describing shouldn't be causing a slow down in UITableViewCell. [Apple developers are much smarter than you and I](http://randomtype.ca/blog/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/) so make sure you've got the data to back up your decision!

I've also seen a lagging UITableViewCell within the simulator with no noticeable difference on real hardware.

It is true that using CoreGraphics can speed up your draw performance but it can also slow it down if you do it wrong! Have a look at the [Apple Tutorial on Advanced Table View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedTableViewCells/Introduction/Intro.html) for how to perform the technique.

Comment: I guess my follow up question is when would it be appropriate to have it drawn as a single view versus a subviews. This is also tested on a device.

Comment: If you can show that your subviews are slowing down the UITableView then start diving into CoreGraphics.

Comment: how do I determine if my subviews are actually slowing down the UITableView? Images are also pre-downloaded

Comment: via Instruments. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459708/measuring-the-uitableview-scrolling-performance-iphone